# Encrypting using RSA/ECB/PKCS1paddding encryption with .cert public key

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

we are trying to encrypt the code with RSA/ECB/PKCs1 code with .cert publickey but we are failing and getting an error "not a valid RSAKey"

```
        public string RsaEncryptWithPublic(string clearText, string publicKey)
        {

           
            publicKey = GetCertificate().PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);
               
                        var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

            var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
            {
                var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

                encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
            }

            var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));
            return encrypted;

        }
```